# how to call (vanilla) websocket.onmessage method in vue instance

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuex

setting up a vue application to have message functionality from vanilla websockets, so no socket.io, etc. the receiving message part is confusing me because its not called in the usual since but once the server pushes a message to the client. the following is what i want to do essentially but is not permitted in  `methods` or `computed` properties

```
this.$store.state.SocketModule.webSocket.onmessage = function (msg) {
  this.$store.dispatch('SocketModule/onmessage', msg)
  // handle the msg in vuex
}
```

so should i do something like;

```
computed: {
  onmessage: this.$store.state.SocketModule.webSocket.onmessage = function (msg) 
    {
      this.$store.dispatch('SocketModule/onmessage', msg)
      // handle the msg in vuex
     }
}
```

would that even work? (havent finished socket server) or something like;

```
<script>
   this.$store.state.SocketModule.webSocket.onmessage = function (msg) {
     this.$store.dispatch('SocketModule/onmessage', msg)
     // handle the msg in vuex
   }
export default {
   ...
```

the server pushing a message instead of fetching the message from the client is different working with